# Functional in the dual space s.t $\psi$ restricted to a subspace equals $\phi$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $W$ be a subspace in a vector space $V$ [you may assume that dim $V$ is finite].
Prove that any $\phi$ in $W^*$ can be extended to a functional on $V$ , i.e. there exists $\psi$ in $V^*$ such that $\psi|W$ = $\phi$. ($\psi$ restricted to $W$ equals $\phi$).

Comment: What did you try? In what context is this question posed?

Answer (score 2):

Let $\,W_F=Span\{w_1,\ldots,w_k\}\,$ , and complete this basis of $\,W\,$ (i.e., a linear independent set) to a basis of $\,V_F\,:\;\;\{w_1,\ldots,w_k\,,v_1\ldots ,v_m\}\,$ . Define now

$$\Phi:V\to F\,\,,\,\,\Phi(w_i)=\phi(w_i)\;,\;\;\Phi(v_j)=k_j\,\,,\,k_j\in F\,\,,\,\forall\,\,i=1,...,k\,\,,\,\,j=1,...,m$$

and extend the definition by linearity to the whole of $\,V\,$ . Clearly $\,\left.\Phi\right|_W=\phi\,$ . Observe you have quite a few extensions for any such functional $\,\phi\,$ .

Comment: By rank-nullity for a surjective functional we have $\dim(\ker)+\dim(\im) = \dim(v)$ so if $V$ is finite dimensional there can only be one basis element that isn't sent to $0$, as $\dim(\im) = 1$.

Comment: First of all I think you're rushing a little too much to downvote. Second, nobody said otherwise: it is well known the kernel of a non-zero linear functional is a hyperplane, meaning it has dimension one less than then whole space's in the finite case and, in any case, it has codimension 1, so: what exactly contradicts this in what I wrote? Did you note the scalars $\,k_j\,$ haven't been determined (in my answer) and, in fact, they all *must* be scalar multiples of $\,\phi(v)\,$ , for **any** $\,v\in V\,$ for which $\,\phi(v)\neq 0\,$ ?

Comment: "Observe you have quite a few extensions for any such functional" contradicts this in the finite dimension greater than 1 case.

Comment: I did remove your downvote though, as I agree that my disagreement with the last claim of your answer doesn't warrant it.

Comment: @DoctorBatmanGod, please do read my **second** answer below as it is too long for a comment.

Comment: You're correct. I sincerely apologize.

Comment: No need to apologize, @Doc, in particular to the honorary president of the "Oh, rats: I made a mistake!" Club, aka me. I think though that we all should ponder a lot our downvotes, both because we can be wrong and also because it doesn't serve a lot more than annoying (sometimes) someone else that's making some effort to help other people.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand, Doc, your problem with my "quite a few" comment in my answer. Shall we do an example? Take $\,W:=\left\langle\binom{1}{0}\right\rangle\,$ , and we complete the basis $\,\left\{\binom{1}{0}\right\}\,$ of $\,W\,$ to the basis $\,\left\{\binom{1}{0}\,,\,\binom{0}{1}\right\}\,$ of $\,\Bbb R^2\,$.

Take for example $\,\phi\in W^*\,\,,\,\phi\binom{1}{0}:=1\,$ , and now I define

$$\Phi_r\in(\Bbb R^2)^*\,\,,\Phi_r\binom{1}{0}:=1\,\,,\,\Phi_r\binom{0}{1}:=r$$

and extend by linearity:

$$\Phi_r\binom{x}{y}=\Phi_r\left(x\binom{1}{0}+y\binom{0}{1}\right)=x+ry$$

For example

$$\Phi_2\binom{1}{3}=1+3\cdot 2=7\;\;,\;\;\Phi_{-4}\binom{1}{3}=1+3(-4)=-11\,,\,etc.$$

How many extension you get? Of course, the codomain of all these non-zero functionals is the same, namely the whole of $\,\Bbb R\,$ , but as functions they all are different...Could it be you're confusing these two things? Of course, perhaps I'm missing something here, but I think the above explains what I meant.